# configuring XB24-ZB in Api Mode

Tags: arduino, zigbee

I am trying to use two Xbees, one coordinator API and one router API, transferring data between them.

I'm facing a problem when trying to the set router X-CTU settings. Pan id as 1234 but the OP-operating Pan id line remains at 0, the OI-perating 16-bit pan id line remains at FFFF and the MY--16 bit Network address remains at FFFE. Shouldn't these fields change?

As for setting the coordinator I didn't have any problems and tried with other Xbees with no success.

I am using Arduino Uno, Wireless SD Shield and Xbee s2.
[image]

Comment: "Here is a screenshot attached:" where? :)

Comment: sorry i forgot that it couldn't let me upload a photo.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p44p9igqjgnxv0j/x-ctu.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The router's operating PAN IDs and network address will change as soon as it's able to join the network established by the coordinator.  `ATAI` will tell you the association status, and could help debug why it's failing to connect.